# Java - Is string object internally referred string pool?

Tags: java, string

I know the difference of the String instance creation and String literal.

What I know is, when we create new string object i.e

```
 String str= new String("xyz");
```

A new object will be created in heap and assigned to local variable str and along with this a string literal will be created in string pool(correct me if I am wrong).

Here what I wanted to know is, **does that newly created object in heap, it self holds the value or it internally points to the string pool?** or **The new object created in heap is holding the value or it just wrapping the value of object which is already there in string pool?**

Comment: You can simply test it yourself. Create the same String again and check if it is *==* which would mean there is a shared pool or it is only *equals* which means no shared pool is used.

Comment: nope, using the new key word will not put the string in the string pool, you will need to use intern

Comment: I guess my question is not clear, in **new String("xyz")** I am using literal **"xyz"** that means the string object will be created in string pool. Here what I am asking is the new object created in heap is holding the value or it just wrapping the value which is there in string pool.

Comment: Upvoted. We can all guess the answer but I wonder what the JLS actually states? Is it allowed to optimise this to refer to an interned string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in the Open JDK and in Oracle's implementation, the String object internally holds a private `char[]` which contains the actual data (up to jdk1.8 at least). When you say `new String("literal")` a new object is created which has a `char[]` field that refers to the same array as the one in the interned string pool.

Comment: You mean to say the char[] which is there in String object will refer to string pool "literal". That means the string object wrapping string pooled object. Am I right?

Comment: That's right. So let's assume class String has a field, `private char[] data`. Then after `String str= new String("xyz");` the following will be true: `str.equals("xyz")`, `str != "xyz"`, `str.data == "xyz".data`. I.e. both fields refer to the same array. This is all implementation-dependent, of course.